# Applying 2 between() queries and reporting in a previous table

Tags: python, pandas

I have data frames

```
data = [[1, 5,2,10], [1, 5,-1,-1]]
 

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['START', 'END', 'g','g2'])


START    END       g            g2
1        5         2            10   
1        5        -1           -1
```

I want to select rows in which g is -1

and do a query with START and END against another data frame like this

```
data = [[2, 10,'foo'], [1, 5,'faa']]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['START', 'END', 'data'])

START2   END2     data
2        10       foo 
1        5        faa
```

The query is an overlapping

```
.query(START.between(START2,END2) | (END.between(START2,END2)
```

If an overlap is found save something in a new column in df1

```
START    END       g            g2    pass_validation
1        5         2            10   
1        5        -1           -1     true
```

I know how to select a row by condition, and I know how to do the query but I cant achieve it altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
df['pass_validation'] = df['g'].eq(-1) & (df['START'].between(df2['START2'], df2['END2']) | df['END'].between(df2['START2'], df2['END2']))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   START  END  g  g2  pass_validation
0      1    5  2  10            False
1      1    5 -1  -1             True
```

Comment: I accept your answer because it answered my question but I wanted to say if not found. How can I invert that??

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. Are you thinking something like this? `df['pass_validation'] = ~(df['g'].eq(-1) & (df['START'].between(df2['START2'], df2['END2']) | df['END'].between(df2['START2'], df2['END2'])))`